# problema con paginación de tablas usando angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, mat-paginator, paginacion

Estoy tratando de implementar una paginación a una tabla, sinceramente creí que funcionaba, pero después de probar me di cuenta de que el rango de la pagina casi nunca funciona, es algo muy extraño lo que pasa, si guardo el archivo.ts varias veces puede que funcione una sola vez, pero luego si recargo la pagina deja de funcionar, o simplemente se establece en 0. que estoy haciendo mal?

Acá explico con imágenes lo que sucede:

las pocas veces que funciona está bien, cuando digo que funciona me refiero a que se muestran los items bien, a medida que voy seleccionando la cantidad de items por pagina, por ejemplo inicialmente se muestran 3:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego si selecciona la siguiente opcion (5), se muestran todos los demás (en total son 4 items los que hay) y se actualiza el rango a: 1 - 4 of 4:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así debería, funcionar.

Pero si recargo la página todo se daña, y sucede esto:

a veces el rango se establece en 0 de 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si por ejemplo, vuel a recarga la pagina entonces cuándo selecciono los items por página el rango no se actualiza nunca, así:

acá estoy en la inicial (3 items por pagina).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si luego selecciono, 5 tems: el rango no se actualiza, sigue igual que antes (aunque si se muestran los ítems):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá dejo el código:

Archivo .ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingBarService } from '@ngx-loading-bar/core';
import { SnackBar} from '../../../services/snackbar.service';
import {UsuarioService} from '../../../services/usuarios.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
// import { DataSource, MatPaginator, Mat} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {environment} from '../../../../environments/environment'
import { PagosModalComponent } from './pagos-modal/pagos-modal.component';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-usuarios',
    templateUrl: './usuarios.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./usuarios.component.css']
})
export class UsuariosComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    // @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    dataSource:any;
    url_api:string = `${environment.URL_API}/`
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['nombre', 'correo','tipo_usuario','options'];
    usuarios:any[]=[];
    // userInfo= {
    //     id_usuarios: '', apellido: '', borrado: '', clave: '', correo: '', 
    //     createdAt: '', nombre: '', recupera_contra: '', tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios: '', updatedAt: ''
    // }
    constructor(
        private usuarioService:UsuarioService,
        private loadingBar: LoadingBarService,
        private snackBar: SnackBar,
        private router:Router,   
        public dialog: MatDialog,

    ){
        this.loadingBar.start()
        this.usuarioService.getUsuarios().subscribe((response)=>{
            // this.loadingBar.complete();
            // this.usuarios= response.payload;
            // //this.dataSource= this.usuarios
            // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(response.payload);
            // console.log(this.usuarios)
            this.loadingBar.complete();
            response.payload.forEach( element=> {
                let userInfo= {
                    id_usuarios: '', apellido: '', borrado: '', clave: '', correo: '', 
                    createdAt: '', nombre: '', recupera_contra: '', tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios: '', updatedAt: '', nombreCompleto: ''
                }
                userInfo.id_usuarios= element.id_usuarios;
                userInfo.apellido= element.apellido;
                userInfo.borrado= element.borrado;
                userInfo.clave= element.clave;
                userInfo.correo= element.correo;
                userInfo.createdAt= element.createdAt;
                userInfo.nombre= element.nombre;
                console.log('*****'+userInfo.nombre)
                userInfo.recupera_contra= element.recupera_contra;
                userInfo.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios= (element.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios==1)? 'Cliente': 'Administrador',  
                userInfo.updatedAt= element.updatedAt;
                userInfo.nombreCompleto= `${element.nombre} ${element.apellido}`;
                this.usuarios.push(userInfo);
            })
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.usuarios);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        },
        err=>console.log(err));
    }
    // buscar(event:any){
    //     const users = this.usuarios;
    //     this.dataSource = users.filter((user:any)=>{
    //         user.tipo_usuario = this.transformTipoUsuario(user.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios);
    //         const userS = JSON.stringify(user);
    //         return userS.indexOf(event.target.value)===-1?false:true;
    //     });

    // }    
    buscar(event: Event){
        const filtro= (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.dataSource.filter= filtro.trim().toUpperCase();

    }

    transformTipoUsuario(id_tipo_usuario:number){
        switch (id_tipo_usuario){
            case 1:
                return "Usuario"
            case 2:
                return "Empresa"
            case 3:
                return "Administrador"
        }
    }
    ngOnInit(){}
    verPedidos(id:string){
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PagosModalComponent,{
            width:'60%',
            data:id
        })
    }
}
```

Archivo .html:

```html
<!-- <p s>Usuarios</p> -->
<nav >
  <ol class="breadcrumb" style="background: transparent;">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item " aria-current="page" [routerLink]="['../']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" 
    >Admin</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item " aria-current="page" 
    >Usuarios</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
<mat-card class="example-card mt-4 mr-3 ml-3">
    <mat-card-content>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <input type="text" mat-input (keyup)="buscar($event)" placeholder="Buscar"
          class="form-control"/>            
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="spinner-container text-center" *ngIf="dataSource === undefined">
          <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
        </div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
           
          
            <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre Completo </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <div >
                  {{element.nombreCompleto }}
                </div>
                
              </td>
            </ng-container>
          
            <!-- Weight Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="correo">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Correo </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.correo}} </td>
            </ng-container>
          
            <!-- Symbol Column -->
        
            <!-- Symbol Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="telefono">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>  </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                <div *ngIf="element.telefono !== null">  +{{element.telefono}} </div>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Symbol Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="tipo_usuario">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tipo Usuario </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
<!--                 <div *ngIf="element.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios === 1">
                  {{element.}}
                </div>  
                <div *ngIf="element.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios ===2">
                  Administrador
                </div>  
                <div *ngIf="element.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios ===3">
                  Administrador
                </div>   -->
                {{element.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios}}
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Symbol Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>  </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                     <a mat-icon-button color="primary"
                     (click)="verPedidos(element.id_usuarios)"><mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon></a>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
          
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
          <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons > </mat-paginator>
          
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

Intenté asignando el paginator en el afterViewInit así:

```js
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log('\nNgAfterViewInit...\n')
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    }
```

pero me muestra este error:

`core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined at UsuariosComponent.ngAfterViewInit (usuarios.component.ts:99)`

Que sucede, siceramente no entiendo que pasa, tengo horas en esto y no he podido resolver. Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

********** [Edición]

arhivo .ts con modificaciones (la paginación sigue funcionando igual que antes, el rango no se actualiza al cambiar los ítems por página):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingBarService } from '@ngx-loading-bar/core';
import { SnackBar} from '../../../services/snackbar.service';
import {UsuarioService} from '../../../services/usuarios.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
// import { DataSource, MatPaginator, Mat} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {environment} from '../../../../environments/environment'
import { PagosModalComponent } from './pagos-modal/pagos-modal.component';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-usuarios',
    templateUrl: './usuarios.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./usuarios.component.css']
})
export class UsuariosComponent implements OnInit  {
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    // @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
    url_api:string = `${environment.URL_API}/`
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['nombre', 'correo','tipo_usuario','options'];
    usuarios:any[]=[];
    // userInfo= {
    //     id_usuarios: '', apellido: '', borrado: '', clave: '', correo: '', 
    //     createdAt: '', nombre: '', recupera_contra: '', tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios: '', updatedAt: ''
    // }
    constructor(
        private usuarioService:UsuarioService,
        private loadingBar: LoadingBarService,
        private snackBar: SnackBar,
        private router:Router,   
        public dialog: MatDialog,

    ){
        this.loadingBar.start()
        this.usuarioService.getUsuarios().subscribe((response)=>{
            // this.loadingBar.complete();
            // this.usuarios= response.payload;
            // //this.dataSource= this.usuarios
            // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(response.payload);
            // console.log(this.usuarios)
            this.loadingBar.complete();
            response.payload.forEach( element=> {
                let userInfo= {
                    id_usuarios: '', apellido: '', borrado: '', clave: '', correo: '', 
                    createdAt: '', nombre: '', recupera_contra: '', tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios: '', updatedAt: '', nombreCompleto: ''
                }
                userInfo.id_usuarios= element.id_usuarios;
                userInfo.apellido= element.apellido;
                userInfo.borrado= element.borrado;
                userInfo.clave= element.clave;
                userInfo.correo= element.correo;
                userInfo.createdAt= element.createdAt;
                userInfo.nombre= element.nombre;
                console.log('*****'+userInfo.nombre)
                userInfo.recupera_contra= element.recupera_contra;
                userInfo.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios= (element.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios==1)? 'Cliente': 'Administrador',  
                userInfo.updatedAt= element.updatedAt;
                userInfo.nombreCompleto= `${element.nombre} ${element.apellido}`;
                this.usuarios.push(userInfo);
            })
            this.dataSource.data = (this.usuarios);
        },
        err=>console.log(err));
    }
    // buscar(event:any){
    //     const users = this.usuarios;
    //     this.dataSource = users.filter((user:any)=>{
    //         user.tipo_usuario = this.transformTipoUsuario(user.tiposUsuarioIdTiposUsuarios);
    //         const userS = JSON.stringify(user);
    //         return userS.indexOf(event.target.value)===-1?false:true;
    //     });

    // }    
    buscar(event: Event){
        const filtro= (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.dataSource.filter= filtro.trim().toUpperCase();

    }

    transformTipoUsuario(id_tipo_usuario:number){
        switch (id_tipo_usuario){
            case 1:
                return "Usuario"
            case 2:
                return "Empresa"
            case 3:
                return "Administrador"
        }
    }
    ngOnInit(){}

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log('\nNgAfterViewInit...\n')
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    }

    verPedidos(id:string){
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PagosModalComponent,{
            width:'60%',
            data:id
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que inicializas el objeto de `dataSource` luego de obtener los datos en el `subscribe` y el método `ngAfterViewInit` se ejecuta antes y el `dataSource` es `undefined` y por lo tanto no puede acceder a la propiedad `paginator` de algo `undefined`.

Para arreglarlo puedes iniciar el `dataSource` cuando la creas con un `[]` vacío.

```javascript
 dataSource:any = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
```

Quitar lo siguiente del `subscribe`.

```javascript
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.usuarios);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

Añadir lo siguiente en el `subscribe` para actualizar el `dataSource`

```javascript
this.dataSource.data = this.usuarios;
```

Y dejar el `ngAfterViewInit` igual.

Comment: Hola @hawks gracias por responder. me dices que le asigne un arreglo vacío al dataSource pero en donde le asignaria this.usuarios (que es donde esta la data para mostrar en la tabla) ?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta

Comment: continúa igual.

Comment: te sale el error en la consola?

Comment: creo que hice todo como dices. arriba cambié: dataSource:any; por:  dataSource:any = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]); en el subscribe coloqué solo esto:  this.dataSource.data = (this.usuarios);  y en el afterViewInit dejo solo esto:  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

Comment: no sale ningun error. solo que sigue funcionando igual que en las imagenes.

Comment: has quitado todo lo de `response.payload.forEach`?

Comment: no no, quise decir que solo quité esto: ```this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.usuarios); this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;``` y agregué esta:  ```this.dataSource.data = this.usuarios;```

Comment: Todo lo demás quedó como estaba (incluyendo el forEach).

Comment: yo creo que lo de `forEach` es innecesario pero por lo demás no lo entiendo

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la data me viene de una forma en la que tengo que recorrerla para poder dejarla en un vector como el que necesito para armar la tabla.

Comment: y el `this.dataSource.data = this.usuarios` lo haces luego del `forEach`?

Comment: Si, afuera del ForEach. @hawks incluso quitando el forEach sigue pasando lo mismo , el rango en la paginación no actualiza cuando cambias los items por página.

Comment: edite la pregunta y al final agregue el archivo .ts como lo tengo actualmente con tus sugerencias para que veas como lo tengo actualmente.

Comment: sinceramente no veo nada mal. Si miras el ejemplo de paginación veras que lo tienes igual. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples. Está un poco abajo

Comment: Estoy revisándolo y veo que al cambiar la cantidad de items por página el rango nunca se actualiza pero en este ejemplo de stackblitz si se actualiza:  https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxxpqbqolyb?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts

Comment: pues no se sorry

Comment: si fuese un error por versión de materialize mostrara un error, corecto ?

Comment: Ya funciona, no se que hice, pero funciona, disculpa tendrás un tiempo para hacerte una consulta al chat y no sequir llenando esto con comentarios?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115508/discussion-between-hawks-and-julianprog).